# Transparency of object in 2.91

Tags: transparency

My mesh is transparent in front view, both in object and edit mode but it shows in side view, what to do to get it visible also in front view?

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: or even better show us your blend file if possible

Comment: Try pressing the numeric / key (a few times) in the front facing window , to see if mesh object is visible in Local Mode.  Know that Blender has multiple ways of controlling visibility.  Groups and Single Objects.  It only takes one stray keystroke or mouse click to create problems.

Comment: Is the image in front of the object?

Comment: Yes the mesh object is visibly in local mode but still transparent in the same way off local mode

Comment: No, the ref pics is behind the mesh

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann ... I think your shocking idea is on the Brink of a solution Mann